# How to select multiple class properties in LINQ Expression?

Tags: linq, lambda

If I have a class like this

```
`
  class Person
  {
    public string First;
    public string Last;
    public bool IsMarried;
    public int Age;
  }`
```

Then how can I write a LINQ Expression where I could select properties of a Person. I want to do something like this (user can enter 1..n properties)

```
SelectData<Person>(x=>x.First, x.Last,x.Age);
```

What would be the input expression of my SelectData function ?

```
SelectData(Expression<Func<TEntity, List<string>>> selector); ?
```

**EDIT**
In my SelectData function I want to extract property names and then generate SELECT clause of my SQL Query dynamically.

**SOLUTION**
Ok, so what I have done is to have my SelectData as

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> SelectData(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> expression)
    {
        NewExpression body = (NewExpression)expression.Body;
        List<string> columns = new List<string>();
        foreach(var arg in body.Arguments)
        {
            var exp = (MemberExpression)arg;
            columns.Add(exp.Member.Name);
        }
        //build query
```

And to use it I call it like this

```
ccc<Person>().SelectData(x => new { x.First, x.Last, x.Age });
```

Hopefully it would help someone who is looking :)

Thanks,
IY

Comment: Have you searched anything before asking? (hint - select many)

Comment: I dont want to select the data. I want to get the properties user has entered in expression. Based on these property names I want to generate SELECT clause for my SQL Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be better to use delegates instead of Reflection. Apart from the fact that delegates will be faster, the compiler will complain if you try to fetch property values that do not exist. With reflection you won't find errors until run time.

Luckily there is already something like that. it is implemented as an extension function of IEnumerable, and it is called [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (irony intended)

I think you want something like this:

> I have a sequence of Persons, and I want you to create a Linq
>   statement that returns per Person a new object that contains the
>   properties First and Last.

Or:

> I have a sequence of Persns and I want you to create a Linq statement
>   that returns per Person a new object that contains Age, IsMarried,
>   whether it is an adult and to make it difficult: one Property called
>   Name which is a combination of First and Last

The function SelectData would be something like this:

```
IEnumerable<TResult> SelectData<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    return source.Select(selector);
}
```

Usage:

problem 1: return per Person a new object that contains the
properties First and Last.

```
var result = Persons.SelectData(person => new
{
    First = person.First,
    Last = person.Last,
});
```

problem 2: return per Person a new object that contains Age, IsMarried, whether he is an adult and one Property called Name which is a combination
of First and Last

```
var result = Persons.SelectData(person => new
{
    Age = person.Name,
    IsMarried = person.IsMarried,
    IsAdult = person.Age > 21,

    Name = new 
    {
        First = person.First,
        Last = person.Last,
    },
});
```

Well let's face it, your SelectData is nothing more than Enumerable.Select

You could of course create a function where you'd let the caller provide a list of properties he wants, but (1) that would limit his possibilities to design the end result and (2) it would be way more typing for him to call the function.

Instead of:

```
.Select(p => new
{
    P1 = p.Property1,
    P2 = p.Property2,
}
```

he would have to type something like

```
.SelectData(new List<Func<TSource, TResult>()
{
     p => p.Property1,     // first element of the property list
     p -> p.Property2,     // second element of the property list
}
```

You won't be able to name the returned properties, you won't be able to combine several properties into one:

```
.Select(p => p.First + p.Last)
```

And what would you gain by it?

Highly discouraged requirement!

Comment: I think its not exactly what I am looking for but still it provides a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could achive similar result using [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) and [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Model:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Person
    {
        public string First { get; set; }
        public string Last { get; set; }
        public bool IsMarried { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Service:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    public static class Service
    {
        public static IQueryable<IQueryable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>> SelectData<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, string[] properties)
        {
            var queryResult = new List<IQueryable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>>();
            foreach (T entity in queryable)
            {
                var entityProperties = new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>();
                foreach (string property in properties)
                {
                    var value = typeof(T).GetProperty(property).GetValue(entity);
                    var entityProperty = new KeyValuePair<string, object>(property, value);
                    entityProperties.Add(entityProperty);
                }
                queryResult.Add(entityProperties.AsQueryable());
            }
            return queryResult.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person()
                {
                    Age = 18,
                    First = "test1",
                    IsMarried = false,
                    Last = "test2"
                },
                new Person()
                {
                    Age = 40,
                    First = "test3",
                    IsMarried = true,
                    Last = "test4"
                }
            };

            var queryableList = list.AsQueryable();
            string[] properties = { "Age", "Last" };
            var result = queryableList.SelectData(properties);

            foreach (var element in result)
            {
               foreach (var property in element)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{property.Key}: {property.Value}");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Age: 18
Last: test2
Age: 40
Last: test4
```